# How do I mock an exported typescript function in a jasmine test?

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, mocking, spy

I'm trying to mock a function exported from a typescript file in a Jasmine test. I expect the following to mock the imported `foo` and return the value 1 in the spec for bar.

The mock appears to be uncalled, so I'm clearly missing something. How can I fix this example?

demo.ts:

```
export function foo(input: any): any {
  return 2;
}

export function bar(input: any): any {
  return foo(input) + 2;
}
```

demo.ts.spec:

```
import * as demo from './demo';

describe('foo:', () => {
  it('returns 2', () => {
    const actual = demo.foo(1);
    expect(actual).toEqual(2);
  });
});

describe('bar:', () => {
  // let fooSpy;
  beforeEach(() => {
    spyOn(demo, 'foo' as any).and.returnValue(1); // 'as any' prevents compiler warning
  });

  it('verifies that foo was called', () => {
    const actual = demo.bar(1);
    expect(actual).toEqual(3); // mocked 1 + actual 2
    expect(demo.foo).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Failures:

- Expected 4 to equal 3.
- Expected spy foo to have been called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jeffery's answer helped get me on the right track.

To attach the spy is attached to the right reference for `foo` the product code needs to have a small change. `foo()` should be called as `this.foo()`

The below pattern works for testing (and is a lot cleaner than the convoluted work around I was using previously).

demo.ts:

```
export function foo(input: any): any {
  return 2;
}

export function bar(input: any): any {
  return this.foo(input) + 2;
}
```

demo.ts.spec:

```
import * as demo from './demo';

describe('foo:', () => {
  it('returns 2', () => {
    const actual = demo.foo(1);
    expect(actual).toEqual(2);
  });
});

describe('bar:', () => {
  // let fooSpy;
  beforeEach(() => {
    spyOn(demo, 'foo' as any).and.returnValue(1);
  });

  it('verifies that foo was called', () => {
    const actual = demo.bar(1);
    expect(actual).toEqual(3);
    expect(demo.foo).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: This is true only for classes. a raw function does not have a this. Well kinda. Typescript complains about it.

Comment: Agree. This is a typical use-case where you'd need an instantiable object that uses a [strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) for each _unit_ you want to be able to mock independently.

Comment: This saved my life, thank you! BTW, how did you get rid of the "'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation."? NVM, I figured it out, it was the noImplicitThis option, not the noImplicitAny

Answer (score 4):

> From [this issue on Github](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1414): How are you expecting to use the spied on function in your actual implementation?

Your `bar` implementation calls the *actual implementation* of `foo`, because it has a direct reference to it. When importing in another module, a new object, with new references, is created:

```
// This creates a new object { foo: ..., bar: ... }
import * as demo from './demo';
```

These references exist only in the module of the import. When you call `spyOn(demo, 'foo')` it's that reference that is being used. You might want to try this in your spec, chances are the test passes:

```
demo.foo();
expect(demo.foo).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Expecting the real implementation of `bar` to call a mocked `foo` is not really possible. Instead try to treat `bar` as if it had its own implementation of `foo`.

Comment: Thank you! This led me to what I needed to solve my problem.