# spyOn local function in another file

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

How can you spy on a function that has been exported, but also called in a function like this:

File 1:

```
export function myFunction(){
  // do stuff
  return myOtherFunction()
}

export function myOtherFunction(){
  // do stuff
}
```

File 2:

```
import * as helpers from './helpers'
beforeEach(()=>{
  spyOn(helpers, 'myOtherFunction');
});
it('should call myOtherFunction', ()=>{
  helpers.myFunction();
  expect(helpers.myOtherFunction).toHaveBeenCalled()
});
```

The problem with this is that `myOtherFunction` will never be called, because jasmine is spying on the wrong object. `myFunction` will call the local function and the jasmine test will expect the exported variable to get called, they are different objects.

Comment: This question looks similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49538472/6361314) I came across some time ago.

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp I agree. I think it is a duplicate, but that other guys solution only works with a class I am exporting just a function.

Comment: The problem here is identical actually. Only the `helpers.myOtherFunction` reference in **File 2** is overwritten. `myFunction` however uses a direct local reference. that is also why your expectation fails. The overwritten reference in **File 2** is actually never called, _only the actual implementation_. The local reference is never going to be anything else, unless explicitly overwritten from within **File 1**.